# Object Expected Error.

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am getting `Object Expected error`.

I am unable to find the reason this error happens.

Can you tell me the senarios when this error occurs?

Comment: Is this in the JSP or JavaScript? Show some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical JavaScript error message, not a JSP error message. JSP is a view technology providing a template for HTML/CSS/JS. When writing JS in a JSP page and having problems with it, it's not caused by JSP, but just by yourself. You would have exactly the same problem when doing so in a "plain" HTML file.

The most common cause of this error message is a syntax error in the JavaScript code or a misspelling in the function name. Verify if your JS code is all right, i.e. there are no missing braces, parens nor semicolons and ensure that all calls to functions are spelled correctly.

Also see [this site](http://javascriptfixer.com/object-expected.php) for more information.